# with tf.Session() as session(): ^ SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Tags: python, tensorflow

In previous code, I tried the below and it worked but it's not working now. Can anyone see the problem?

```
with tf.Session() as session():
    session.run(init)
```

But now I am getting this error. From looking at other posts, it seems to be because other people are using brackets when they should be using parenthesis. But I'm not using brackets and I can't see what is wrong.

```
    with tf.Session() as session():
        ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Comment: `with tf.Session() as session:` Those brackets at the end `()` is an incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with tf.Session() as session():
```

is somewhat same as:

```
session() = tf.Session()
```

which produces the same error because parentheses `()` after `session` makes Python think left-hand side is an expression which is syntactically and semantically wrong, thus you should remove them:

```
with tf.Session() as session:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it!

Answer (score 0):

> In previous code, I tried the below and it worked but it's not working now.

Well that's simply impossible because

```
with tf.Session() as session():
```

is a syntax error in **every** Python. What you want is

```
with tf.Session() as session:
```

without those brackets `()` at the end.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:

    a = tf.constant(3.0)
    b = tf.constant(4.0)
    c = a+b

    print(sess.run(c))

    sess.close()
```

7.0